# Copy all views from Linked Server into new database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powerquery

In SQL Server Management Studio, I have a Server Object-> Linked Server where there are cube views. I am trying to make a copy of all of these views and save them on a separate SQL database on same server so that I can connect to these new views using things like PowerBI and Power Query. Any suggestions as to how I would go about doing this? I know that I could write individual queries such as:

```
Select * INTO [new_table] from [linked_server_view].[Table]
```

However there are hundreds of views in the Linked Server and this would be very time consuming. 
Thanks,

Comment: Can you use Visual Studio with an SSDT project via Schema Compare?

Comment: That wouldn't copy the views, only the current data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using your initial idea of writing the individual queries would be to get SQL to write the queries for you. Run something like

```
SELECT 'select * into ' + name + ' FROM linkedserver.database.schema.' + name
FROM linkedserver.database.sys.views
```

Copy the results, paste into editor, and run.

You can modify the query as needed. I was just showing the basic idea of using SQL to produce the query for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    'select ' + '* into ' + TABLE_NAME +  ' from ' + TABLE_CATALOG + '.' + TABLE_NAME

FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'View'
```